# Lubridate error: ‘/etc/localtime’ is not a symlink

Tags: r

When I run `now()` in lubridate I get this error.

> Warning: Your system is mis-configured: ‘/etc/localtime’ is not a
> symlink Warning: It is strongly recommended to set environment variable
> TZ (time zone) to ‘Etc/Universal’ (or equivalent)

Then I get the current time tuned to UTC.

`[1] "2019-04-14 15:50:18 UTC"`

I've looked around for this on SO and github and I'm not finding much content. I'm running RStudio Server on a Linux box on EC2.

Here is the top of the output from sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03
```

I looked for the timezone options in `/usr/share/zoneinfo/` and saw `Pacific` which matches up with my timezone. I ran `Sys.setenv(TZ='Pacific')`, but it still serves the wrong time.

```
[1] "2019-04-14 16:15:04 Pacific"
Warning message:
In with_tz(Sys.time(), tzone) : Unrecognized time zone ''
```

Comment: Please read at least `help("Sys.timezone")` in base R to see some relevant minimal information about time zones -- and pay attention to the Sections _Details_ and _Warnings_. This is a pretty loaded topic.  One way to set timezone information, if you have to, is via either your personal `~/.Renviron` or, if you can, the system-wide `Renvron.site`.  See `help("Startup")` for details on  how.

Answer (score 4):

We need more information to help you -- "on a Linux box" is not all that specific.

Looking at the function in question we see

```
 R> lubridate::now
 function (tzone = "")
 with_tz(Sys.time(), tzone)
 <bytecode: 0x55fd86dd68a8>
 <environment: namespace:lubridate>
 R>
```

so a base R call of `Sys.time()` coupled with some package-specific code to get to the timezone.

Now, how timezone information, something somewhat specific to the local installation, is provided to R is *not* standardized. Hence the error message.

I needed it once for another package (of mine) and R (at the time) was not doing enough -- so see

```
 R> gettz::gettz()
 [1] "America/Chicago"
 R>
```

R has since improved and added a very similar heuristic (of looking in other possible places) so it is more robust.  So please test some more and tell if R knows the timezone even if `lubridate` does not.

In either case, you could (should ?) set it to help the system.

And if R finds it, why not just use base R?

```
R> format(Sys.time(), "%F %T %Z")  
[1] "2019-04-14 11:06:54 CDT" 
R>
```

Comment: You never answered my question about what base R shows.

Comment: I have this problem now on RHEL6 and I don't control the server (I can whine at the people who do if necessary).  R does find the timezone just fine with `Sys.time())` so I'm going to use the base R solution provided by @DirkEddelbuettel.  Thanks Dirk!

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the timezone on your local system. Timezones like "Pacific" are invalid in R and timezones like "PST" are vague. For instance, EST exists in Amercia, but it also exists in Australia.

R uses international standard IANA time zones and you can find a list of valid timezones [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

You can set the timezone for your local system with `Sys.setenv(TZ='America/Los_Angeles')`

If you want to learn more about working with dates, see [this chapter](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/dates-and-times.html) from Hadley Wickham's and Garrett Grolemund's *R for Data Science.*

Comment: I would delete this answer if I were you.  All the relevant information _is_ in base R, see the comments I just left below your question.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when loading lubridate on an EC2 machine running Amazon Linux 2. It can be resolved by running `sudo timedatectl set-timezone UTC` at the bash prompt. You can replace `UTC` with whatever timezone you prefer from the list produced by `timedatectl list-timezones`.